# clearInterval doesn't work (React-Native Javascript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, setinterval, clearinterval

I am currently working on a React-Native app, for some reason I am unable to clear the interval that I have set earlier. It simply wont work no matter what I try. here's my code if you guys could give it a look I would greatly appreciate it. It's all inside a Gesture Handler.

```
  const rotation = useSharedValue(0);
  const pullDistance = useSharedValue(0);
  const rotationValue = useSharedValue(0);
  const stretchTo = useSharedValue(0);
  var animationLoop;

  const animation = (rot) => {
    const EASING = Easing.elastic(1.5);
    animationLoop = setInterval(() => {
      rotationValue.value = withSequence(
        withTiming(-10 + rot, {
          duration: 100,
          easing: EASING,
        }),
        withTiming(10 + rot, {
          duration: 100,
          easing: EASING,
        })
      );
    }, 200);
  };

  const clearAnimation = (animationLoop) => {
    clearInterval(animationLoop);
    rotationValue.value = 0;
    console.log("cleared");
  };

  const pullingToMatchGestureHandler = useAnimatedGestureHandler({
    onStart: () => {
      console.log("start");
      console.log("animating");
      const rotationValue = rotation.value;
      pullDistance.value = 1;
      runOnJS(animation)(rotationValue);
    },

    onActive: (event) => {
      const direction = 0;
      const distance = Math.sqrt(
        Math.pow(event.translationX, 2) + Math.pow(event.translationY, 2)
      );
      if (event.translationX > 0 && -event.translationY > 0) {
        direction = Math.atan(-event.translationY / event.translationX);
      } else if (event.translationX < 0 && -event.translationY > 0) {
        direction =
          Math.PI + Math.atan(-event.translationY / event.translationX);
      } else if (event.translationX < 0 && -event.translationY < 0) {
        direction =
          Math.PI + Math.atan(-event.translationY / event.translationX);
      } else if (event.translationX > 0 && -event.translationY < 0) {
        direction =
          2 * Math.PI + Math.atan(-event.translationY / event.translationX);
      }

      let rotationInRad = (rotation.value * Math.PI) / 180;
      rotationInRad = -rotationInRad + Math.PI / 2;
      while (rotationInRad < 0) {
        rotationInRad = rotationInRad + 2 * Math.PI;
      }
      const differenceAngle = rotationInRad - direction;
      if (
        -distance * Math.cos(differenceAngle) > 0 &&
        -distance * Math.cos(differenceAngle) < window.width / 5
      )
        pullDistance.value = -distance * Math.cos(differenceAngle) * 2.5;
    },

    onFinish: (event) => {
      console.log("end animation");
      runOnJS(clearAnimation)(animationLoop);
      cancelAnimation(rotationValue);
      pullDistance.value = 0;
    },
  });
```

The log('cleared') runs so there shouldn't be a problem in the execution of the clearAnimation function. I dont know what to do.

Comment: You should log the value of `animatioonLoop` when you first set up the interval timer, and then log it again in `clearAnimation()` so you can verify that you're clearing the right thing.

Comment: @Pointy lemme try that real quick

Comment: @Pointy it says that in both cases animationLoop is undefined, which means the the clearInterval isn't getting the right value. What can I do to change this?

Comment: @Yogi Just tried that, still not working.

Comment: `runOnJS`,   Don't use `react-native`, but this sounds like your JS is running inside separate context.   As such you maybe need to use -> `useSharedValue`  to store the interval.

Comment: @Keith I'm not sure what exactly you mean by this.

Comment: In your code, can you see how you have used `useSharedValue` for rotation etc, why not do the same for `animationLoop`?.  The interval was created inside `runOnJS` so logic would imply your interval would need creating in the same place.  IOW: The animationLoop inside `animation` will be creating a global not accessing `var`, as it's not in same JS context.

Comment: @Keith You just saved my life! Ly boss

Comment: Nice one, I'll knock up a an answer so you can close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be with JS runtime context, I don't use React Native, but from what I can gather it uses worker threads (worklet) to keep the GUI nice and responsive.

So ->  `var animationLoop;` is potentially not running in the same JS context as code that's been run in `runOnJS`   This then means the interval created inside these `runOnJS` will not see this `var`.

The solution appears to be use `useSharedValue` to store the interval Id, this can then be shared between each `runOnJS`.